# How to query a Simple Machines Forum for topic popularity/rating

Tags: php, c++, html, simple-machines-forum

Is there a way(or API) to queue a remote SMF site to get the top/popular topics of a particular time frame, say past 24 hours? If not, any suggestions as to how I could track this?

Comment: Is this a remote SMF site that you own (that you could provide database access to, or an API method of your own)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is that's possible but i know where is "API" from SMF side that enables you to call latest posts. Check this out: http://wiki.simplemachines.org/smf/Using_SSI.php